# Isinstance() doesn't work

Tags: python

For some reason I can't get isinstance() to work on Python 2.7.2

```
def print_lol(the_list, indent=False, level=0):
    for item in the_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            print_lol(item, indent, level+1)
        else:
            print(item)
```

And when I compile and run it:

```
>>> list = ["q", "w", ["D", ["E", "I"]]]
>>> print_lol(list)
```

I get the error message:

```
if isinstance(item, list):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

What am I mising?

Comment: Everybody makes a `list` called `list` in almost every python problem on SO...

Comment: @jamylak It's a mistake almost everyone has to make once  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've named your variable `list`:

```
>>> list = ["q", "w", ["D", ["E", "I"]]]
```

Which is hiding the built-in `list`.

Once you've renamed your variable, restart Python (or your IDE). Since your `list` is a global variable, it will stick around otherwise.

Comment: You can also re-bind `list` manually: `import __builtin__; list = __builtin__.list` will do the trick in this case.

Comment: @torek: that's not the ideal way; the best way is `del list`. Then `list`  will go back to being the built-in type.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: interesting, never knew that before.  Doesn't work with other (non-builtins) overwrites that you want to recover from in the interpreter, of course. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is where you have issue

```
>>> list = ["q", "w", ["D", ["E", "I"]]]
```

overwriting python named types like `list` binds the variable name with a new object instance. So later when you tried isinstance with list it failed.

When ever you create new variable, please refrain from naming it differently from built-in and not to conflict with the namespace.

In this example using the following would work like a breeze

```
>>> mylist = [w for w in mylist if len(w) >= 3 and diff(w)]
>>> isinstance(mylist,list)
True
```

Please note, if you have polluted the namespace and you are running in IDLE, restarting IDLE is a good alternative.

Comment: It doesn't "bind a new behavior to an existing type". The type still functions exactly the same, the ___name___ just doesn't point to the type any more.

Comment: @agf: Ahh typo I mean bind to a variable

Comment: It doesn't bind _anything_ to something existing. It creates a name, `list`, in the global namespace, which hides the `list` name in the `builtin` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have shadowed the built-in `list` by assigning to a variable called `list`:

```
list = ["q", "w", ["D", ["E", "I"]]]
```

You should try to avoid using any of the built-in names for variables, because this will often result in confusing errors. The solution is to use a different name for your variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `list`, try `print list` before `isinstance` to diagnose this sort of problem.